# Logo image not showing on transactional emails in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, email, transactional-mail

The image path is accurate in all cases i.e. image file is present but not showing

I have tried following solution for changing templates:

```
<img src="{{skin url='images/logo_email.gif' _area='frontend' _package='danone'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/>
```

This is the logo image path when viewing it on gmail:

```
<img src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lnE8J-8Wm44xakzqQyA74i1dYSiVIiXPJBmNwtm5K-61OImYZeiV9hBlYKkhEBJJvHB8wT15GTbNL5IQ_oLt7cYC7EiKmaR1kj96q1Zby8mWQ5n6mCiuoV5sqJI=s0-d-e1-ft#http://danone.local/skin/frontend/danone/default/images/logo_email.gif" alt="" style="margin-bottom:10px" border="0" class="CToWUd">
```

On my local host there is no htacess. what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The transaction email does not attached the image inline. It is loaded from the server when the email is opened. Based on the example you provided, I'm going to guess you are sending the email to a Gmail account to test. When you do that, Google proxies the image to protect your identity by not having your IP hit the Magento server.

Either move the image to a publicly accessible location or setup a staging server to test the whole site on a public server. Since Google can't hit your local server, that image will never load.

Answer (score 2):

put a logo_email.gif also in skin/frontend/base/default/images and try again. also if you are on a mac give permissions 777 to this file or check all permissions folders. Finally , why you do not have htaccess?No good to go for developing even in local machine. If you are on Xampp or whatever try to fix rewrites and use htaccess.

Comment: I meant  site is not password protected, say via an htaccess file or something similar. I checked the permision and I also renamed the logo to logo_email.gif using gimp. I am on ubuntu linux and running zendserver. but still i experience this issue

Comment: wait to understand.. now that i read better your post, do you expect google to find your image in you local server?This is not possible. Google is trying to http://danone.local but there is no domain name on this. if you want to do live test then you should open port 80 on your router , find your ip adress and configure magento to run on http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/danone or whatever name you want. And of course test your site first if the port is open  and everybody can see website (make a test site in tools.pingdom.com or any other method , even access it from another ISP)

Answer (score 0):

Open the new email template, load any template and click on Preview. After preview click on the logo. It will show the path where Magento picks it. Go to the path, delete previous logo and upload. Your problem will be solved.